# JavaScript: Change Class Style across various pages

Tags: javascript, css, dom

I was trying to create a function that would allow me to change the color of a div in my footer on every page on `mouseover`.

This is what I have come up with so far and its not working.

JavaScript:

```
function A(obj) {
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName(obj)
    var objects = []

    for (var i=0; i < elements.length; ++i) {
        objects.push(elements[i])
    }
    return objects;
}

var footerDiv = A('footerDiv');
footerDiv.onmouseover = function() {
    footerDiv.style.color = 'black';
}

footerDiv.onmouseout = function() {
    footerDiv.style.color = 'white';
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="footerDiv">
  Example Text
</div>
```

Comment: Isn't the whole function `A(obj)` just equivalent to `document.getElementsByClassName(obj)`?

Comment: Why don't you do this with CSS?

Comment: @fuzic +1, but to be precice, actually, It's a `NodeList` see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementsByClassName

Comment: @fuzic: Almost. It's basically `Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName(name))`, which converts the NodeList into an Array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd do this with just CSS:

```
.footerDiv {
    color: white;
}

.footerDiv:hover {
    color: black
}
```

Comment: +1 This is probably the best approach for what OP is trying to accomplish. Might worth mentioning that he failed because he was trying to apply style to an array and not an element.

Comment: Thanks guys, I was just trying to see if its possible to do it strictly from javascript. If it is too complicated I'll definitely just do it with CSS thanks!